# How to search for track based on track name and artist in spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I need to retrieve a song for the user based on song name and artist name (so I get the correct one). The end goal is to get the track id.
Here is the code I thought would work:

```
searchResults = spotifyObject.search(q="artist:" + artist + "track:" + searchQuery, type="track")
```

Where artist is the name of the artist/band and searchQuery is the name of the track.
This should return a JSON block for the specific track but instead returns:

```
{
"tracks": {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=artist%3AHarry+Stylestrack%3AWatermelon+Sugar&type=track&offset=0&limit=10",
    "items": [],
    "limit": 10,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total": 0
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a space between the artist and the `track:` tag.

BEFORE

```py
searchResults = spotifyObject.search(q="artist:" + artist + "track:" + searchQuery, type="track")
```

AFTER

```
searchResults = spotifyObject.search(q="artist:" + artist + " track:" + searchQuery, type="track")
```

Comment: This was it - thanks Rusty Widebottom

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is of any help, but in spotipy's definition of the function, 'track' is the type by default, so if you pass both artist and song name into the query, there are 99% chances you get what you are searching for. You can try something like this:

```
searchQuery = track + ' ' + artist
searchResults = spotifyObject.search(q=searchQuery)
```

Getting this as a result using `track="New Rules"` and `artist="Dua Lipa"` (I included parameters `market="US"` and `limit=1` for the purpose of this example):

```
{
  'tracks': {
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=New+Rules+Dua+Lipa&type=track&market=US&offset=0&limit=1',
    'items': [{
      'album': {
        'album_type': 'album',
        'artists': [{
          'external_urls': {
            'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we'
          },
          'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we',
          'id': '6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we',
          'name': 'Dua Lipa',
          'type': 'artist',
          'uri': 'spotify:artist:6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we'
        }],
        'external_urls': {
          'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/01sfgrNbnnPUEyz6GZYlt9'
        },
        'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/01sfgrNbnnPUEyz6GZYlt9',
        'id': '01sfgrNbnnPUEyz6GZYlt9',
        'images': [{
          'height': 640,
          'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2736b915e407b70e121e06fe979',
          'width': 640
        }, {
          'height': 300,
          'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e026b915e407b70e121e06fe979',
          'width': 300
        }, {
          'height': 64,
          'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d000048516b915e407b70e121e06fe979',
          'width': 64
        }],
        'name': 'Dua Lipa (Deluxe)',
        'release_date': '2017-06-02',
        'release_date_precision': 'day',
        'total_tracks': 17,
        'type': 'album',
        'uri': 'spotify:album:01sfgrNbnnPUEyz6GZYlt9'
      },
      'artists': [{
        'external_urls': {
          'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we'
        },
        'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we',
        'id': '6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we',
        'name': 'Dua Lipa',
        'type': 'artist',
        'uri': 'spotify:artist:6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we'
      }],
      'disc_number': 1,
      'duration_ms': 209320,
      'explicit': False,
      'external_ids': {
        'isrc': 'GBAHT1600310'
      },
      'external_urls': {
        'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/2ekn2ttSfGqwhhate0LSR0'
      },
      'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/2ekn2ttSfGqwhhate0LSR0',
      'id': '2ekn2ttSfGqwhhate0LSR0',
      'is_local': False,
      'is_playable': True,
      'name': 'New Rules',
      'popularity': 81,
      'preview_url': 'https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/75a1b521de23958a2db9acf4fc8151999ee54bd7?cid=aba114e12c4b474895556922ce1a572d',
      'track_number': 10,
      'type': 'track',
      'uri': 'spotify:track:2ekn2ttSfGqwhhate0LSR0'
    }],
    'limit': 1,
    'next': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=New+Rules+Dua+Lipa&type=track&market=US&offset=1&limit=1',
    'offset': 0,
    'previous': None,
    'total': 53
  }
}
```

Comment: just found out this answer and, for some reason, your solution works. The query in the form of `'track:' + title + ' artist:'` + artist doesn't work instead

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to use the API call links provided by Spotify, look through the following documentation in Spotify Developers (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/). *Don't forget to gain an access token after you log into your account*

```
import request
import pprint

url = "#link_created_through_spotify_api"
r = request.get(url)
dictionary = r.json() # Turn call info into dictionary
print("Status code:", r.status_code) # Print status code to see if the call was successful.

pprint(dictionary)
```

The `pprint` module will allow to print the dictionary in a very formatted and organized way. A status code of 200 would mean the call was successful. Hope this somewhat helps.